# Sliding Content one by one, otherwise show all contents

Tags: jquery, html, css

My site is sliding content vertically. But what's happen: If i'm on home screen, and want to click on the last menu item (Newsletter) .. the sliding show ALL contents before reach the destination link (Newsletter)..

So.. i want to know, what i need to do to slide only the menu item i have clicked, otherwise all contents.

This is my working site with this problem: http://www.alsite.com.br/luxxx

And this is my sliding script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //get all link with class panel
        $('a.panel').click(function () {

                    //reset and highlight the clicked link
            $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            //grab the current item, to be used in resize function
            current = $(this);

                    //scroll it to the destination
            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

                    //cancel the link default behavior
            return false;
        });


        //resize all the items according to the new browser size
        $(window).resize(function () {

            //call the resizePanel function
            resizePanel();
        });

        function resizePanel() {

    //get the browser width and height
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    //get the mask height: height * total of items
    mask_height = height * $('.item').length;

    //set the dimension     
    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: width, height: mask_height});

    //if the item is displayed incorrectly, set it to the corrent pos
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}


    });
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just hide all other screens except the one you're currently showing and the one you want to show and slide over. If you can put a `.current` class on the one you're currently looking at, here's how you can do it:

```
$('.item').hide();
$((this).attr('href')).add('.current').show();
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
```

Comment: To expand: Set all the other divs to display: none (or I suppose .hide()) to collapse them. Except the CURRENT div and the div you want to scroll to.

Comment: i dont know if i'm doing this right, but dont work.

`$(this).addClass('selected current');` and i put the code you provide me

Comment: another problem is, the scroll animation is lost. This work only on first time you click on any menu. But the sliding effect is lost..

Comment: well, you have to show the ones you want to see before you scroll to them! i updated my code for you

Comment: Now, even the first link does not appears